# Convert without accepting mitzvos?

Tags: sources-mekorot, conversion-to-judaism, kavana-intent

Conversion is always a hot topic, especially here in Israel. Many times conversions take place where the Ger (convert) didn't have the intention to be m'kabel (accept) the mitzvos. People scream and shout, but seemingly the conversion (according to some) would be still be kosher!

The Rambam writes in Hilchos Issurei Bia Perek 13 Halacha 17:

גר שלא בדקו אחריו או שלא הודיעוהו המצות ועונשן ומל וטבל בפני ג' הדיוטות ה"ז גר. אפילו נודע שבשביל דבר הוא מתגייר הואיל ומל וטבל יצא מכלל העכו"ם וחוששין לו עד שיתבאר צדקותו. ואפילו חזר ועבד כו"ם הרי הוא כישראל מומר שקידושיו קידושין. ומצוה להחזיר אבידתו מאחר שטבל נעשה כישראל. ולפיכך קיימו שמשון ושלמה נשותיהן ואע"פ שנגלה סודן

Although this seems b'dieved clearly the Rambam holds that if the person did not know about the mitzvos (thus did not accept them) that they would still be considered a Jew.

The Bach writes in Yoreh Deah Siman 268 that according to the Rambam if the potential Ger didn't accept the mitzvos,
"כשר אע"פ שלא היה לשם קבלת מצוות כל עיקר".

Although the Shulchan Aruch doesn't rule like this l'halacha I'd like to know if there are any other Rishonim or earlier poskim that also held like this?

Comment: "... seemingly the conversion (according to some) would be still be kosher!" but still forbidden to do. That part gets kind of skipped over in this argument, and the first part was tenuous enough. See what the Bach in the same place says about what a horrible disservice is being done to the non-Jew who gets converted without going on to keep the Mitzvos.

Comment: @Yishai I'm doing research myself now and finding many that held this way and not with such strong language as forbidden to do or "disservice"...

Comment: I look forward to your answer, but note that the Rambam is very clear that it is forbidden to do so.

Comment: The Rambam is nearly universally understood to require *kabbalas hamitzvos bifnei sh'losha* even *b'di'avad* (i.e. it is *m'akeiv* the conversion). The Bach is the only classical source that understands the Rambam as saying that the conversion is valid even if the convert did not accept the *mitzvos* in front of a court of three (even the Bach would probably interpret the Rambam as invalidating a convert who apparently intended not to accept the *mitzvos* at all). And the Bach continues and says this opinion is wrong. So no one both interprets the Rambam that way and says it can be followed.

Comment: Aside from the Bach, all classical sources interpret the Rambam according to its plain meaning, i.e. that the conversion is *b'di'avad* valid even if the court failed to inform the convert of individual commandments and the repercussions of observance or non-observance (according to one reading of the Rambam) or if the court just failed to inform the convert of the repercussions of observance or non-observance (according to the alternative reading of the Rambam that fits with the Shulchan Aruch). Either way the Rambam requires the convert to accept the overall burden of *mitzva* observance.

Comment: Also, the Bach (YD 268, "vechal inyanav" near the end) doesn't even rule like (his understanding of) the Rambam. He explains the Rambam in his own way, and then ends up saying but the halakhah is like the Tosafos, Rosh and Shulchan Arukh.

And as noted by @Yishai, even if the geirus is valid bedi'eved, actually performing the milah utevilah lesheim geiros is prohibited.

However, some posqim believe that already being a citizen in the Jewish state changes the pro-vs-con balance, even changes what it means to accept mitzvos -- since one can join the people in other ways.

Comment: I recommend R YH Henkin's (the Benei Banim) discussion in Hakira, available at http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%207%20Henkin.pdf

He disagrees with R' Druckman, but respectfully defends his shitah as valid. Thus giving a relatively fair presentation of the issues.

Comment: @MichaBerger, I haven't read it, but it would seem you could work R. Henkin's discussion into an answer.

Comment: @MichaBerger I realize the Bach argues but he is the one what clearly understood the Rambam to mean that only milah and tevilah is enough. There are those that argue on what the Rambam "meant".

Comment: I was just saying that from a poseiq's point of view, the Bach's interpretation of the Rambam carries no weight (at least, none because the Bach said it).

Yes, if/when I had more time, a summary of RYHH's essay would make a good answer.

Comment: @MichaBerger The Shach write in Hilchos Horah (which appears before Hilchos Talmud Torah I believe in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah) that essentially b'shas hadhach you could be somach on a shitas yachid. So depends what type of "psak" you are referring to or considering.

Comment: But it's not even a shitas yachid. To be a shitah, it has to be what the rav holds lehalakhah. The Bach made a theoretical point -- we don't hold like the Rambam, but this is what he held. If we hold like the Bach, we are following the Shulchan Arukh. If we hold like acharonim who actually hold like the Rambam by their understanding, conversion still requires qabbalas ol mitzvos. There is no one we know for sure said we do not require such qabbalah.

Comment: @MichaBerger I will bli neder put an answer together soon with many that understood this Rambam like the Bach. SO I think it is an acceptable shitas yachid...Until Moshiach comes!